# DAP 1650 - What is the login password for the telnetd server?

Tags: telnet, wireless-extender

I have a D-Link Wireless AC1200 dual band gigabit range extender (DAP-1650) and was trying to get into the telnetd server but I haven't got a password. I tried some of the usual ones: admin, password, blank but no go

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is stored inside of the firmware itself. All you need to do is extract SquashFS and search for the "telnet" string.
Pay attention and you will find it.

Comment: Sorry yes this is what I ended up doing but forgot to come back

Comment: That's ok, but try to remember answering your questions if you found the answer.
https://xkcd.com/979/